# UPD: Парсить данные с Ютуба YouTube

Tags: php, парсер, youtube, simple-html-dom

**Задание:**
Спарсить блок лицензии конкретно заданного видео на YouTube.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Для этого подключил библиотеку *«Simple Html Dom Php»*

```js
<?php
    require 'simple_html_dom.php'; //подключаем библиотеку
    $link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdmBTTAFlk0';
    $html = file_get_html( $link ); // получаем страницу

    $load = file_get_contents( $link );
    $html= str_get_html( $load );

    echo $element = $html->find('#collapsible', 0);
?>
```

Однако никакого результата не выдает. Тогда как тот же запрос на другие сайты - работает.
Нужно **именно спарсить** данные. Youtube API и oEmbed не рассматриваются.

Comment: удивительно, но если открыть указанную ссылку, затем нажать "Исходный код страницы", то вы там не найдете `id="description"`

Comment: @teran Да, спасибо. Только что искал. Оказывается у них исходный код зашифрованый скриптами. В таком случае поможет библиотека PhantomJS чтобы получить полностью отработанную страницу в обычном DOM-формате?

Comment: контент самого дескрипшена поищите в теле страницы. он там небось в каком нибудь json зарыт. можно попробовать выцепить весь объект целиком и json_decode ему сделать, либо какой-нибудь регуляркой попробовать достать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для последующих искателей подобных вопросов: `"Как парсить динамические страницы с помощью PHP?"`
**Ответ простой: Никак.**
Потому что PHP - серверный язык. Он не видит исполнения .js скриптов, которые нужны для полной загрузки и отработки страницы.

С помощью библиотеки *«Simple Html Dom Php»* можно парсить только статические страницы.
Этот вариант мне не подходит, поэтому перешел на `Python + Selenium`.

К Python подключил request_html. И BeautifulSoup для парсинга HTML-страниц, который умеет извлекать скрипты для дальнейшей работы. Уже такого арсенала хватит для большинства задач. Однако искомый мною блок подгружается JSON'ом после расскрытия блока `"Подробнее"`.
Для решения подключаем `Selenium` который нужен для управления браузером.

Продолжение в другой теме: [Не удается получить содержимое с помощью Beautiful Soup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1188741/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-beautiful-soup)

Answer (score 0):

Вы изобретаете очередной велосипед, просто используйте oEmbed (https://oembed.com/)
например есть видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0

для него делаете запрос

```
https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0&format=json
```

для него получается ответ

```
{
    "thumbnail_height": 360,
    "html": "<iframe width=\"480\" height=\"270\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
    "height": 270,
    "title": "PSY - GANGNAM STYLE(강남스타일) M/V",
    "provider_name": "YouTube",
    "author_url": "https://www.youtube.com/user/officialpsy",
    "type": "video",
    "author_name": "officialpsy",
    "thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9bZkp7q19f0/hqdefault.jpg",
    "provider_url": "https://www.youtube.com/",
    "thumbnail_width": 480,
    "version": "1.0",
    "width": 480
}
```

формат можно как json так и xml
oEmbed кстати очень многими сервисами поддерживается

Comment: Спасибо за наводку по поводу oEmbed, однако вопрос стоит именно о парсинге YouTube-страницы и вот почему:
В вопросе я навел пример о парсинге блока #description для более простой наглядности. 
Вытащить именно описание гораздо проще с помощью API YouTube подобным выражением: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={VIDEO_ID}&part=snippet&key={MY_KEY}"
На самом деле мне нужен элемент лицензии видео, который ни с API YouTube, ни тем более с oEmbed не достать.
Вот в этом и заключается вопрос: «Как парсить закодированную скриптами ютуб страницу?»
Спасибо за внимание!