# Не удается получить содержимое с помощью Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, youtube

**Задание:** спарсить блоки названия и лицензии видео на YouTube с помощью Beautiful Soup

По запросу `result["title"] = soup.find("h1").text.strip()` успешно получаем название видео.
А вот `result["license"] = soup.find("ytd-metadata-row-renderer").text.strip()` выдает ошибку *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот весь код:**

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

# init session
session = HTMLSession()


def get_video_info(url):
    # download HTML code
    response = session.get(url)
    # execute Javascript
    response.html.render(sleep=1)
    # create beautiful soup object to parse HTML
    soup = bs(response.html.html, "html.parser")
    result = {}
    ################### FROM HERE!!!
    # video title
    result["title"] = soup.find("h1").text.strip()
    # video license
    result["license"] = soup.find("ytd-metadata-row-renderer").text.strip()
    return result
    ################### TO HERE!!!

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="YouTube Video Data Extractor")
    parser.add_argument("url", help="URL of the YouTube video")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    # parse the video URL from command line
    url = args.url
    
    data = get_video_info(url)

    # print in nice format
    print(f"Title: {data['title']}")
    print(f"License: {data['license']}")
```

Получаем с помощью запроса в терминале: `python getVideoLicense.py https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdmBTTAFlk0`

**В результате должно вывести:**

```
Title: ТРИ МІШКИ  | 29 варіантів як подолати стіну з мішків | Україна  
License: Пісня - Rollin' (Air Raid Vehicle) (Radio Edit)  
Виконавець - Limp Bizkit  
Writers - Fred Durst, Kasseem Mike Dean, Redman, Earl Simmons, Clifford Smith  
Ліцензію для YouTube надали - UMG (від імені студії звукозапису "Interscope"); UNIAO BRASILEIRA DE EDITORAS DE MUSICA - UBEM, UMPI, LatinAutorPerf, ASCAP, UMPG Publishing, Warner Chappell, BMI - Broadcast Music Inc., LatinAutor - Warner Chappell, CMRRA, LatinAutor - UMPG, PEDL та організації, що володіють правами на музику (25)
```

Comment: Выведи в консоль просто soup и посмотри имеется ли там этот элемент. Скорее всего, там JS. Тогда парсить только через Youtube либо использовать Youtube Data API v3

Comment: @danilshik Да, действительно через JS. Что имеешь в виду под "парсить только через Youtube". YouTube API и oEmbed не подходят, так как там нет этой информации. Буду рад любому совету!

Comment: Можно открыть страницу с помощью selenium в браузере и спарсить содержимое после подгруженных скриптов.

Comment: Да я Selenium имел ввиду =)